# How to count data where sum is greater than x

Tags: sqlite, count, having-clause

I am very new to SQL and am using SQLite 3 to run basket analysis on sales data.

The relevant columns are the product ID, a unique transaction ID (which identifies the basket) and the product quantity. Where a customer has bought more than one product type, the unqiue transaction ID is repeated.

I am wanting to count the number of baskets where the customer has bought 1 item.

So far I have tried `select count(distinct uniqID) from salesdata having sum(qty) = 1;`

But this brought up an error saying `a GROUP BY clause is required before HAVING`.

I then tried `select count(distinct uniqID) from salesdata group by uniqID having sum(qty) = 1`

SQlite accepted this, but returned me a list of just 1s, which isn't right either!

I then tried `select count(uniqID) from salesdata group by qty having sum(qty) = 1`

SQlite also accepted this but returned nothing at all.

Any ideas would be hugely appreciated!

E

Comment: Just use sum(qty)>1 or any value u want ,since you are using sum=1 so group by will return only results where sum=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this to retrieve every user which has more or equal than one item in his basket

```
select uniqID, sum(qty) as total from salesdata group by uniqID having total >= 1
```

if you want to have only the users which have 1 item in their baskets replace `>=1` with `=1`

like:

```
select uniqID, sum(qty) as total from salesdata group by uniqID having total = 1
```

If you want the numbers of users with 1 item in their baskets you get this like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (select uniqID, sum(qty) as total from salesdata group by uniqID having total 
= 1)
```

Comment: This still does not return the amount of users which have only one item in their basket. I think `select count(uniqID) from (select uniqID, sum(qty) as total from salesdata where qty = 1 group by uniqID having total = 1)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the number of baskets that have only one item. This will also filter out baskets with a quantity higher than one on one single item. If you don't want that, remove the `WHERE qty = 1` part.

```
  SELECT 
    COUNT(uniqID)    FROM 
    (SELECT 
      uniqID, SUM(qty) AS total 
     FROM 
      salesdata 
     WHERE 
       qty = 1 
     GROUP BY 
       uniqID 
     HAVING 
       total = 1)
```